# python3 subprocess email attachment

Tags: python, email, python-3.x, subprocess

How to add attachment to subprocess in python 3  ?  I can send a mail without issue but not an attachment.

```
import subprocess


recipient = 'test@test.com'
subject = 'test'
body = 'testing mail through python'
path = '/home/Errors.log'


def send_message(recipient, subject, body):
    try:
      process = subprocess.Popen(['mail', '-s', subject, recipient, '-a', path],
                                 stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    except Exception as error:
        print (error)

    process.communicate(body.encode('ascii'))


send_message(recipient, subject, body)    
print("sent the email")
```

Comment: how would you add the attachment in the shell?

Comment: Try using `smtp` python library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html.